# Why does adding a rect then setting its left and top cause a selectable 'ghost' rect to stay in the old position?

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I'm new to Fabric.js and really liking it, but I'm getting odd behavior trying to run a tutorial example at http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1/ . The code is simple:

```
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  var rect = new fabric.Rect({left: 0, top: 0, fill: 'red', width: 50, height: 50});
  var text = new fabric.Text('click\nhere', {left: 0, top: 0, fontSize: 14});
  text.set('selectable', false);
  canvas.add(text, rect);
  rect.set({ left: 50, top: 50 });
  canvas.renderAll();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r7v43b3y/2/

But there seems to be a bug: Run the fiddle, hover your mouse above the text (don't click yet), and note that cursor changes to a cross, indicating there's a Fabric object beneath the mouse, even though it's been moved but Fabric doesn't seem to know that. Now click where the text is (it's not selectable) and notice that you're clicking on a 'ghost' object - the rect is actually elsewhere, but clicking in its old location selects it at its new one. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `rect.set({ left: 50, top: 50 });` put `rect.setCoords();` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks! I'm really surprised that an explicit call to http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#setCoords after http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#set is required, but so be it. What's the thinking? One might want to call set() on the same object multiple times before viewing it? Hmm...

Comment: kangax (the creator of fabricJs) said "This is done on purpose, for performance reasons." ... So he probably knows better :)